# Finding the index of the maximum element in c++ matrix?

Tags: c++, algorithm, search, vector, matrix

I am translating a python(sage) program into a C++ program.

I need to write a function manipulates matrices, and I need to find the **index** of the largest element in the matrix.

I want to do this as efficiently as possible, but the only thing I came up with so far seems quite inefficient.

The pseudo-code for my algorithm is,

1. Given a matrix, call max_element function in each row
2. Create a vector and push_back the iterators returned from max_element
3. Dereferencing the iterators, call max_element function once more
4. Find the index of column
5. Find the index of row

This will be very messy and slow..
Does anyone have a better algorithm to do this task?
Thank you.

Comment: it's vector<vector<int> >, and the matrices is randomly generated and passed into this function

Comment: On step 2, instead of a vector, create a heap.

Comment: @Nick, I considered it, too, but I cannot get the index of the column then.

Comment: You can write your own comparison object on a priority_queue (heap), create a struct with index and value and compare according to value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably easiest just to write the outer loop yourself:

```
if (matrix.size() == 0 || matrix[0].size() == 0) {
    // matrix is empty, handle special case
    throw std::logic_error("empty");
}
int best = matrix[0][0];
size_t rowidx = 0, colidx = 0;
for (auto it = matrix.begin(); it != matrix.end(); ++it) {
    auto maxit = max_element(it->begin(), it->end());
    if (*maxit > best) {
        best = *maxit;
        rowidx = it - matrix.begin();
        colidx = maxit - it->begin();
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you could write an iterator class that iterates over the whole matrix:

```
struct MatrixIterator : std::iterator<std::forward_iterator_tag, int> {
    typedef vector<vector<int> > Matrix;
    Matrix &m;
    size_t rowidx, colidx;
    explicit MatrixIterator(Matrix &m, size_t row = 0, size_t col = 0) : m(m), rowidx(row), colidx(col) {};
    int &operator*() { return m[rowidx][colidx]; }
    MatrixIterator &operator++() {
        ++colidx;
        if (colidx == m[rowidx].size()) {
            colidx = 0;
            ++rowidx;
        }
        return *this;
    }
    MatrixIterator operator++(int) {
        MatrixIterator result = *this;
        ++*this;
        return result;
    }
    bool operator==(const MatrixIterator &rhs) {
        return rowidx == rhs.rowidx && colidx == rhs.colidx;
    }
    bool operator!=(const MatrixIterator &rhs) {
        return ! (*this == rhs);
    }
    static MaxtrixIterator end(Matrix &m) {
        return MatrixIterator(m, m.size() - 1, m.back().size());
    }
};
```

Now you can do:

```
MatrixIterator result = std::max_element(MatrixIterator(m), MatrixIterator::end(m));
size_t rowidx = result.rowidx, colidx = result.colidx;
```

Comment: Thank you. That helps. Actually though, I had to find the index of the max element in a matrix and then proceed to the next submatrix(from (1,1) to (n,n)), and then to the next submatrix((2,2) to (n,n)) and so on, until I do the last one ((n-1,n-1) to (n,n)). Do you think still this is the best way?

Comment: Oh, I think if I add just one more for loop with (int i = 0; i < matr.size(); ++i) outside the first function, and do matrix.begin()+i and it.begin()+i, it will do what I described, right?

Comment: @user2418202: Yes, either of the bits of code I've written could be adapted to operate on only a bottom-right submatrix. Start from row `k` and in each row, start from column `k` instead of 0. If I cared about efficiency I would probably calculate them in the opposite order. The max of the bigger matrix is either the max of the smaller matrix or else it's the max of the extra row and column, so you could do less work in total. That's not very cache-friendly, though, so perhaps it could be improved on further.

Comment: One last question. Isn't this reversed? It seems to me that colidx = it - matrix.begin(); and rowidx = maxit - it->begin();, but you wrote         rowidx = it - matrix.begin();
        colidx = maxit - it->begin();

Comment: @user2418202: you have a choice with your matrix representation, whether each of the vectors represents one row or one column. I have assumed that it represents one row, and so the iterator that starts from `matrix.begin()` counts through the rows. If your matrix is the other way around then that's fine, adjust accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you are storing your data in a two dimensional vector.

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
vector<vector<int>> Matrix
```

You should be able to just iterate your matrix like this to obtain the largest element

```
int MaxValue = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < Matrix.size(); i++) {
    if( *std::max_element(Matrix[i].begin(),Matrix[i].end()) < MaxValue ) continue;
    MaxValue = *std::max_element(Matrix,Matrix+Columns);
}
```